# About CMD little cleanup script

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I have a command-line script that deletes all folder names not listed in a text file. What I would like is for the script to delete ONLY the folders in the text file. I'm not sure what is wrong.
My cmd is:

```
for /d %%a in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Somedir\*") do findstr /i /x /c:"%%~nxa" Cleanup.txt || rd /s /q %%a
```

and my textfile includes short folder names like:

```
am
ar
bg
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I believe you need to replace `||` with `&&`. your current command deletes the directory if the previous command failed (the findstr), so instead, you want to delete when the command succeeds. Of course, you want to test carefully. findstr will return lines if the sought term is a substring of the dir its checking, so if you have `abc` in the file, it will return `abcd`, `abc1`, `xyzabcd`, etc, so it will be much harder to control as written. you may need to use regex so you can do `^abc$`.  see here for details: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html

Comment: Yes, thats right, need to replace || with &&, and working well!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In command-line:

```
cd "C:\Where\Your\Text\File\Is"
for /f %A in ("Cleanup.txt") do (if exist "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Somedir\%A" rd /s /q "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Somedir\%A")
```

In batch:

```
@echo off

set "dir=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Somedir"
set "txt=C:\Where\Your\File\Is\Located\Cleanup.txt"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%A in (%txt%) do (
    set "del=%%A"
    if exist "%dir%\!del!" rd /s /q "%dir%\!del!" 
)
```

Remember to change your directory in the command-line if you're not looking to add anything else to your loop options. I prefer using batch and variables, so I've included that.

Comment: It´s working well also!
Thank you!

Comment: No problem; accepting answers with the checkmark is both really appreciated and has the added benefits of helping people with a similar problem find the solution, and helping people looking to answer questions know what has already been successfully answered.

Comment: I think its going too complicated, but is that Somehow possible, that line `"set "dir=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Somedir"` listed also in text file or in same batch file listed multiple directories?

Like:

`C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Somedir
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\anotherdir` ?


@mael

Comment: @rein I'm not sure I understand your question - you can change the directory variable (`dir`) to any location you want and the batch file will delete the listed text files from it. If you want to do multiple folders at a time we can loop it if that is required, or you can just add those folders the same way the current folder is there: `if exist "whateverfolderyouwant\!del!" rd /s /q "whateverfolderyouwant\!del!"` - you can just add that line under the current `if exist` line, and you can basically add as many as you want.

Comment: My language not good, but u understand me Incredibly well.:)
My batch file is right now like this:

`@echo on

set "dir=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Somedir"
set "txt=C:\Windows\Cleanup.txt"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%A in (%txt%) do (
    set "del=%%A"
    if exist "%dir%\!del!" rd /s /q "%dir%\!del!" 
)

set "dir=C:\sss"
set "txt=C:\Windows\Cleanup.txt"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%A in (%txt%) do (
    set "del=%%A"
    if exist "%dir%\!del!" rd /s /q "%dir%\!del!" 

)`

And it works. But is the way, how can improve?